# gitlab jobs are pending but i have active runners

Tags: gitlab, cicd

Im trying to setup a CI/CD enviroment but when I try to run the jobs it says that the job is stuck and don't have any runners online but when I go to settings [job is stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVm87.png) I can see that I have a created runner and that it is running[online runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hcd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check job tags in your .gitlab-ci.yml
(https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#tags)

In you case, it should be:

```
job:
  tags:
    - testing
```

or remove tags sections if your runner allows running jobs without any tags.